# wrap image into div yet maintain aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

the image flow out the div, I expect it fit within the wrap because I've set width to the div wrapper. The image maybe not the same size for all, so I didn't set the img to a certain fix width to maintain it aspect ratio.

[demo link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/293mW/)

```
profile-pic-wrap {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
img {
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left the `.` out of your class. But event with that (http://fiddle.jshell.net/293mW/1/) the image will pop out of the div. You could add `overflow:hidden;` to the div, but that will crop the image (http://fiddle.jshell.net/pzDVd/).

You probably want to use a background image instead and the `background-size: cover;` or `background-size: contain;` rule. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

**[jsFiddle example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/293mW/2/)** (or http://fiddle.jshell.net/Fhnk8/)

```
.profile-pic-wrap {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    background-image: url(http://naijaparrot.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/mark-zuckerberg-le-fondateur-de-facebook.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: use overflow hidden seem do the trick, the result is the same with using background img.. why?

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to `background-size: cover;` (not contain) and that's just because cover will scale it to fit "while ensuring both its dimensions are greater than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area". And background images can't poke out of their container.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code to solve your problem. This will resize any image into the container while maintaing the correct aspect ration.

Also, you should try to avoid `background-size: cover` because browser support is poor for older browsers.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/293mW/4/

```
.profile-pic-wrap {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
img {
    width:100%;
    max-width: 100%
    height: auto;
}
```